# How to handle csrf tokens in a Laravel 6 - Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, laravel

I am building a todo app with Laravel 6 and Angular 8 and I am having this error thrown

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 419, statusText: "unknown status", url: "http://localhost:8000/api/edit/1", ok: false, …}
error: {message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException", file: "C:\xampp\projects\todo_app\laravel_todo_app\vendor…\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php", line: 208, trace: Array(36)}
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: () => {…}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/edit/1: 419 unknown status"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 419
statusText: "unknown status"
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/edit/1"
```

My laravel controller: 

    `public function update(Todo $todo)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'completed' => 'required'
        ]);
        $data = request()->all();
        $todo->name = $data['name'];
        $todo->description = $data['description'];
        $todo->completed = $data['completed'];
        $todo->save();
        return $todo;

    }`

my Angular : 

 `this.taskService.updateTask(this.id, result).subscribe(res=> console.log('res'), err=> console.log(err))})
  }`

All my routes are on my web.php file

Comment: U need to ensure that you are sending the CSRF token along with your requests. You can add `X-CSRF-TOKEN` as a constant to your angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t work with Laravel 6, but  if i have work 5.x, it´s possible that it´s disable crfs in kernel laravel.
 `

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
           // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```

you can try this, it´s possible thats works.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! I added the path of the concerned pages in the except method of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware. But I was concerned if it was safe or no.

Comment: Sorry my english is very poor. But if i don´t understand bad, you can work this way, you can send csrf to angular, but i don´t remember  how make this, but i you want you can generate tokens for the forms, it´s a possible alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php file and add your route.

```
protected $except = ['your_route'];
```

CSRF is enabled by default on all Routes in Laravel 5+. 
Perfectly Safe!